# Kafka- "Received -1 from channel reading from source socket has likely been closed"

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka

I first create a topic test using the command

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

Then when I try to insert a new message to a topic in Kafka using the command

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:2181 --topic test
```

Then I enter a message like `"name":"Ashish"`

I get the error

> "received -1 from channel reading from source socket has likely been
>   closed" !

What am I doing wrong here?

Any pointers to the solution or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--broker-list` arguments expect to have the Kafka broker Id not the zookeeper one. In your case you have mentioned the zookeeper host:port which is running at port `2181`. By default kafka broker listen on port `9092`.

Change `--broker-host localhost:2181` to `--broker-host localhost:9092` to see if it helps (assuming the kafka broker is running in the same machine, otherwise replace lcoalhost with the machine ip)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I changed it to port number 9092 and executed the command again like [code]/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test [/code] and it worked. So I enter a JSON string like 'name':'Ashish' and press [code]ctrl+C[/code] to save and exit. But now when I try to view the messages in the topic using the command [code] /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test [/code] there is no output on the console? Please suggest what should be done?

Comment: Press enter to publish your message , not Ctrl + C . the cursor will come to the next line to receive another input. BTW it will be useful if you check the formatting options in SO. It will help you post your code nicely

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But then what do I do to terminate the message entry? I sure will read the formatting options in SO. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Ctrl+C will terminate the session. Once you are done with publishing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now, that the messages have been added successfully, I issue the command 
<code>/usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test </code> 
but nothing happens..I dont see the messages listed in the topic. And when I issue the command 
<code> hadoop jar /opt/camus/camus-example/target/camus-example-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob -P /opt/camus/camus.properties </code>
I see a long list of error messages. Should I post it as a new question?

Comment: can you check if the topic exists ?

Comment: Yes, the topic exists because when I issue the command <code> kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181</code> I see a list of topics that I had previously created. And if I issue the command <code> kafka-console-consumer -zookeeper localhost:2181 -topic test --from-beginning</code>to list the messages in the topic, the messages are listed.

Comment: the solution was that the messages inserted in the topic were not in the correct JSON format that is why I was getting the error. After, remedying the problem the error message goes away